# Geeky terminal for OS X

Tags: mac, terminal

I want to bind a certain command to show a terminal on screen without window frame with the command of my choice. I plan to use it to quickly launch network monitoring tools (trafshow) when I use a certain key combination. I should be able to specify the position of the terminal window, make it non-interactive, etc. I can specify the position and options through config file or command-line.

Is there any software I can use or does any of the popular terminal applications have this feature?

Answer (score 2):

Try [GeekTool](http://projects.tynsoe.org/en/geektool/). Might be interesting to you.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might want to consider [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/)? (formerly Visor)